# Saving User inputs at end of Shiny session?

Tags: r, input, shiny, save, session-state

I am trying to make Shiny App which allows users to save inputs and later load them.

Easiest way to approach this, is to make Save button, which saves inputs. Here is basic app to demonstrate:

server.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
sliderInput("integer", "Integer:",
            min = 0, max = 1000,
            value = 500)
),

mainPanel(tableOutput("values"),
actionButton('save_inputs', 'Save inputs')
)

))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    value = input$integer
  })

  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })

  observeEvent(input$save_inputs,{
    saveRDS( input$integer , file = 'integer.RDS')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, I would like to make saving automatic, e.g. I want inputs to be saved at end of session. onSessionEnded() should be answer to this, but it can't reach input values and save them.

```
 session$onSessionEnded( function() {
   saveRDS( input$integer, file = 'integer.RDS')
 })
```

Which returns error: Warning:

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not
>   allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something
>   that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *isolate* seems to solve the problem.

```
 session$onSessionEnded(function() {
   isolate(saveRDS( input$integer, file = 'integer.RDS'))
 })
```

Comment: Very strange, I'm glad you figured it out though! I would set this as the answer if it works btw.

Comment: Yep, I will. Still have to wait one day to mark my own comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using another observe event function and watching the value of isClosed() we can 
 make this work

```
observeEvent(session$isClosed()==T,{
saveRDS( input$integer, file = 'integer.RDS')
})
```

observeEvent() as well as reactive() are both considered "reactive" environments which means they are watching for changing values throughout the session and not just on startup. If you put a function that needs to be reactive outside of a reactive environment shiny will do you the favor of sending you that error, to inform you the function would never be called unless we wrap it in a reactive function.

Also +1 for the well composed question.

Comment: Thanks for an answer! However, with your solution, values seem to be saved at the start of the session rather than at the end, which is really odd. I have tried similar solution to yours, but only using onSessionEnded() previously and it has the same problem.